# ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name after updating to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2

**Magento 2.4.4**

I updated from 2.3.3 to 2.4.4 and now I am getting the following error when the compilation is running:

```
MiBget_class_methods(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name, string given#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Definition/Runtime.php(44): get_class_methods('PPBraintreeApplePayIsActivePlugin')
```

Any idea how to solve this? It seems to be related to Braintree?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you have removed the generated folder content and then run the compile command. If not then give Try to rm -rf generated/ then bin/magento setup:di:compile & check.

Comment: Yes, I removed the generated folder ... does not help.

Answer (score 1):

For those who run into this error on setup:di:com : Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name, string given framework/Interception/Definition/Runtime.php(44) you can do the following:

find that file and add the following bit of code:

```
public function getMethodList($type)
{
    $methods = [];
    // start adding
    if(isset($type) && is_string($type)) {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('type is '.$type);
    }
    // done adding
    $allMethods = get_class_methods($type);
    if ($allMethods) {
        foreach ($allMethods as $method) {
    ...
```

Run setup:di:com once, open the custom.log file, go to the very bottom and note the faulty type. In my case (as above) it was also BraintreeAchIsActivePlugin... no use trying to find it! Especially because it turned out to be a virtual type declaration... Just add to the commandline the following line:

```
 grep -r -H "BraintreeAchIsActivePlugin" *
```

And wait... you'll get the faulty module, in my case (and probably the one above) it was amasty/module-single-step-checkout/

Maybe update it or remove it altogether?

Comment: In my case, the file with the Argument #1 error was  `vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php`, but adding the `if(isset($variable) ...` code above to the function calling the error (in my case `getParents($className)`)helped me figure out which file was the culprit. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to follow

https://gist.github.com/pierzakp/25d37ad05723f4e414493b1f5784b3a0

I had a same issue which is fixed after following steps mentioned in above link

Comment: I applied the fix and still have the same issue, any other suggestions?